# Panel set Invisible/Visible

Tags: .net, winforms, panel

When I set a panel of a form invisible in the constructor, I cannot set it to visible after. I set Visible = true, but it will not be shown. Does somebody seen the same problem and can give me a tip, how to solve this or whats the reason for this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Is the constructor called a second time, after you've put Visible to true? Just thinking out loud.

Comment: make sure your panel is on the top and not covered by other containers.

Comment: Panels normally have the same color as the background, then actually it could be visible but you could have not noticed that. Or, as @Bolu said, it could be hidden by other controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the Problem:
There was a Eventhandler which was bound to the Visible_Changed-Event and make the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I try to create a Form with a Panel, and set it to invisible in the constructor

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    panel1.Visible = false;
}
```

and a button which shows that Panel after it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     panel1.Visible = true;
}
```

and evertything works.

Maybe place your code here, so I or someone else could help.